# iMac G4/800 (2.1) - nouveau or nv?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xubuntu, powerpc

I'm having fun getting Ubuntu going on an old PowerPC G4 iMac with integrated nVidia grahics - Geforce 2 MX / NV11.

(Fun of course is the goal, as the likelihood of this old system being useful is quite low, but hey.)

I successfully installed Ubuntu using the mini-ISO installation method, and opted for the Xubuntu desktop, as I've had success with Xfce on Intel PCs with NV10-series video hardware. (Not with nouveau, but with nVidia's old proprietary drivers which obviously aren't available for PPC.)

I am able to log in to a shell with the yaboot arguments `Linux nomodeset single` as recommended by numerous FAQs out there. If I don't put `nomodeset` in the argument, I get the psychedelic lava-lamp color-cycling-of-doom crashout.

`dmesg` tells me that nouveau crashes out during boot (after looping 103 times):

`nouveau E[     DRM] GPU lockup - switching to software fbcon`

My questions:

1) I know that the hardware should be OK for Xfce based on my PC-world experiences with Xubuntu and NV10-series hardware. Is is possible to finagle/tweak nouveau to 'work' with my NV11 chipset and Xfce? (Most online guides say 'no, just use `nv`, and I never had luck on PC getting Nouveau going on NV10 hardware without significant display issues)

2) If nouveau cannot be made to work, can the `nv` driver be successfully compiled and used on 14.04 with Xfce?

3) Should I stop wasting time and simply downgrade to Ubuntu 12.04? Many sources claim that this works 'best' out of the box, and `nv` can be made to work under this O/S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself just for historical reasons. I no longer have this hardware.

I ended up just downgrading to Xubuntu 12.04 and using nv - under this configuration the system worked fairly well - good enough to be Freecycled to a a new home (where the person just ended up reinstalling Mac OS)

There just was no way that I could find to make nouveau work properly with that particular NV10 chipset.

Answer (score 1):

I have an iMac G4 with a clock frequency of 1 GHz and the same graphics card. Currently my mum is using it, running [Debian](http://debian.org/) 7.7 (stable). In the past I experimented a lot with the computer, having tried Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, and even YellowDog Linux. Debian was the least trouble, especially more recently, where PPC support is declining everywhere. I don't think I had to do anything special to get the graphics running.

Anyway as far as I know nouveau is much better than the nv driver. Did you confuse "nv" with "nvidia", the proprietary driver? I don't think that can be made to run under PPC, since it contains/ depends upon a "binary blob" for x86.

After all Ubuntu is based on Debian, so both largely use the same configuration tools.

Comment: No mistake. The PowerPC web resources all cite 'nv' as the driver to go to if Nouveau can't be made to work - up to Ubuntu 12.04. That being said, I've never been able to get nouveau to work nicely with NV10 / NV11 hardware on x86 - I put Xubuntu on those PCs with the nvidia proprietary driver and had good success.

Comment: What desktop environment are you running on your G4 by the way?

Comment: There were various problems up to 2010, like [fonts being "chipped"](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=21124#c8), or [the backlight not turning off](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29685) - but these all got fixed. Now I see my Mac actually had a GeForce 4 MX, [NV17](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/#nv10family)... so that could make a big difference, sorry! I used various desktops on the Mac (1.5 GByte RAM), from WindowMaker to KDE 4... but now it's simply Xfce.

Comment: Well, Debian 7.7 behaves 100% identically to Ubuntu 14.04 (no surprise, really) - the only way the system can boot is with 'nomodeset'

Comment: Yes, KMS was one of the big advantages of Nouveau... the other being transparent terminals, which I really like. But apart from that nv used to work ok for me. I once had a GeForce 2 MX for PC, which probably led me to confuse my iMac's graphics with yours. Nouveau developers still care about [NV10](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51477) & [NV11](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78748): I easily found two bug reports... maybe you'll be lucky with a new driver version soon? According to the first report 1.0.11 (in **Debian unstable**) fixed some issues.

Comment: 1.0.11 = 100% identical behaviour.